# image viewer not remove dynamically at current position

Tags: android

When i click  current delete image icon of image viewer then delete other position image but i want delete particular position image delete of image viewer. If image size is 3. then i get found image position 1 2 2. Again back then i get found position 2 0 0.

My Activity is :

```
    public class OnlySelectGridViewScreen extends BaseActivity {

    public static OnlySelectedFullImageAdapter adapter;
    public static ViewPager viewPager;
    private static final int TAKE_PHOTO_CODE = 0;
    private ArrayList<String> imagePaths;
    private static final String TAG = "OnlySelectGridViewScreen";
    private TextView tvHeader;
    private GridView gridView;
    private int columnWidth;
    String[] selectImages;
    private int imgPosition = -1;
    private String locName, deptName, cusFolderName, realImagesDirectory;
    private ImageView btnDelete;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.full_image_screen);

        imagePaths = new ArrayList<String>();
        Intent i = getIntent();
        locName = i.getStringExtra("locName");
        deptName = i.getStringExtra("deptName");
        cusFolderName = i.getStringExtra("cusFolderName");
        realImagesDirectory = i.getStringExtra("realImagesDirectory");

        selectImages = i.getStringArrayExtra("selectImages");
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), TAG+"\n SelectImages size :"+selectImages.length, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        List<String> l = Arrays.<String> asList(selectImages);

        // if List<String> isn't specific enough:
        imagePaths = new ArrayList<String>(l);
        tvHeader = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHeader);
        tvHeader.setText("" + locName + " / " + deptName + " / "
                + cusFolderName);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        int position = i.getIntExtra("position", 0);

        adapter = new OnlySelectedFullImageAdapter(
                OnlySelectGridViewScreen.this, imagePaths, locName, deptName,
                cusFolderName, realImagesDirectory);
        if (imagePaths.size() > 0) {
            viewPager.clearFocus();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        // displaying selected image first
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
        btnBack = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backNow);
        btnDelete = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);


        // delete Current image

        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                File file = new File(imagePaths.get(imgPosition));
                boolean deleted = file.delete();
                if (deleted) {
                    Toast.makeText(OnlySelectGridViewScreen.this,
                            "Image delete successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                    imagePaths.remove(imgPosition);
                    // start of update part
                    if (imagePaths.size() == 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getBaseContext(),
                                "Not image found, so add image or back to previous page.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {

                        int position = 0;

                        adapter = new OnlySelectedFullImageAdapter(
                                OnlySelectGridViewScreen.this, imagePaths,
                                locName, deptName, cusFolderName,
                                realImagesDirectory);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        viewPager.clearFocus();
                        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

                        // displaying selected image first
                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
                        // end of update part
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(OnlySelectGridViewScreen.this,
                            "Sorry, Image delete fails.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();

                }

            }
        });

    }

    public class OnlySelectedFullImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        private Activity _activity;
        private ArrayList<String> _imagePaths;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private String locName, deptName, folderName, realImagesDirectory;

        // constructor
        public OnlySelectedFullImageAdapter(Activity activity,
                ArrayList<String> imagePaths, String _mLocationName,
                String _mDeptName, String _mFolderName,
                String realImagesDirectory) {
            this._activity = activity;
            this._imagePaths = imagePaths;
            this.locName = _mLocationName;
            this.deptName = _mDeptName;
            this.folderName = _mFolderName;
            this.realImagesDirectory = realImagesDirectory;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return this._imagePaths.size();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
            return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {
            TouchImageView imgDisplay;
            imgPosition = position;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) _activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View viewLayout = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.layout_fullscreen_image, container, false);

            imgDisplay = (TouchImageView) viewLayout
                    .findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);
            // Get the dimensions of the View
            // int targetW = imgDisplay.getWidth();
            // int targetH = imgDisplay.getHeight();

            int targetW = 100;
            int targetH = 100;

            // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
            BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_imagePaths.get(position), bmOptions);
            int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
            int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

            // Determine how much to scale down the image
            int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW / targetW, photoH / targetH);

            // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
            bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
            bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_imagePaths.get(position),
                    bmOptions);
            imgDisplay.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            ((ViewPager) container).addView(viewLayout);

            return viewLayout;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);

        }

    }



}
```

full_image_screen.xml file is below:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- Header aligned to top -->

    <include
        android:id="@+id/header"
        layout="@layout/header" >
    </include>

    <!-- Footer aligned to bottom -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#0c95d4"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="center" >



            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/img_selector"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/delete_icon_black" />




        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Content below header and above footer -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/footer"
        android:layout_below="@id/header" >

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And Adapter layout_fullscreen_image.xml file is beow:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.databizsoftware.cg.helpers.TouchImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgDisplay"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And finally header.xml file is below :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="5" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvHeader"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:text="Fixed Header"
            android:textColor="#33b5e5"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iHome"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/img_selector"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="goToHome"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:src="@drawable/home_black" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ilogout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/img_selector"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="logoutAction"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logout_black" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dip"
            android:background="#33b5e5" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Why not delete current position of image viewer. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
Implement pageChangeListener and you can achive this.

 viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener(){

            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg) {

            }

            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
               imgPosition = position;
            }

        });
```